# File not found error when using GridFSBucket openDownloadStream

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, filestream, gridfs

I am able to upload a file using openDownloadStream of GridFSBucket and see that the file is uploaded and visible under songs.files chunks. But for some reason, get the following error while trying to download it -

```
Caught exception: Error: FileNotFound: file def1.txt was not found
```

My code is -

```
var express = require('express');
var gridModule = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var fs = require('fs');

gridModule.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("::::grid");
    //const gridfs = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(mongoose.connection.db);

    //const writeStream = gridfs.openUploadStream('test.dat');

    var gridfs = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(mongoose.connection.db, {
        chunkSizeBytes: 1024,
        bucketName: 'songs'
    });

    fs.createReadStream('./def.txt').
        pipe(gridfs.openUploadStream('def1.txt')).
        on('error', function (error) {
            assert.ifError(error);
        }).
        on('finish', function () {
            console.log('done!');
            process.exit(0);
        });

});

gridModule.get('/', (req, res) => {
    var gridfs = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(mongoose.connection.db, {
        chunkSizeBytes: 1024,
        bucketName: 'songs'
    });
    /* var bucket = new mongodb.GridFSBucket(db, {
        chunkSizeBytes: 1024,
        bucketName: 'songs'
      }); */

      gridfs.openDownloadStream('def1.txt').
        pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./def1.txt')).
        on('error', function(error) {
            console.log(":::error");
          assert.ifError(error);
        }).
        on('finish', function() {
          console.log('done!');
          process.exit(0);
        });
});

module.exports = gridModule;
```

I tried using ObjectId id as well but same error. Anyone any guesses what I may be doing wrong here?

Note - Code may not seem optimized here like declaring bucket twice, kindly ignore it for now as I will correct it once it works.

Comment: can you check using `openDownloadStreamByName`? because if you're using a filename you should use that

Comment: @AritraChakraborty, that's deprecated, isn't it? They say it [here](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/client/gridfs/GridFSBucket.html)

Comment: you're checking the `Java` api doc. this is the latest v3.1 api doc for [node js](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/GridFSBucket.html#openDownloadStreamByName)

Comment: @AritraChakraborty, hey my bad. And 10/10 for pointing that out. `openDownloadStreamByName` works, referring a wrong link confused me. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: cool. let me post it as an answer for the other `lost souls` :-p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the API doc [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/GridFSBucket.html#openDownloadStreamByName), in order to use `filename` as argument you should use

```
openDownloadStreamByName(filename, options)
```

not `openDownloadStream`. openDownloadStream takes `id`
 of the file.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible explanation for this, if you're already calling openDownloadStream and still experiencing the FileNotFound error, and you are 100% the id is correct, is that you didn't pass a MongoDB ObjectId type.

In my case, I was passing an id *string* instead of an id as an ObjectId.

```
bucket.openDownloadStream(new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id));
```

vs

```
bucket.openDownloadStream(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb');

bucket.openDownloadStream(new ObjectId(id));
```